# Basic question about calculating the general solution in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

To calculate the general solution, I know to find x(particular), as we call it in my class, by augmenting matrix A with the given b and reducing the augmented matrix until equations may be solved. I can use zero for any and all free variables to find a this x(particular).

For x(special), I'm confused. Do I augment A with the zero vector and solve? Or, do I use the same set of equations that I used for x(particular) and use 1 for the first free variable and zero for any subsequent free variable?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to solve $Ax = b$ via gaussian elimination? I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Could you give an example, so that others can tell exactly what your difficulty is?